# What is the best word or phrase for, 'giving without expectation of receiving anything in return.'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I learned from an earlier thread that the word, love, is not an action verb in English, it is a stative verb.  I learned love from the ancient Greek word, Agape, which is to give without expectation of receiving anything return. A common definition of agape is 'unconditional love,' but if love is a stative verb, and all states are conditional, then 'unconditional love' does not accurately reflect agape.  Is there a single English word or phrase that accurately reflects that definition of agape, an action verb, or should I use agape instead?

Furthermore, 'without expectation' is a bit impossible, since everything we do includes some degree of expectation.  For example, if I agape someone, there is a good chance it's because it is emotionally pleasing to me (unconscious)...and thus, I get something in return.  So, I'm not asking for 'no' return, I'm asking for 'no conscious expectation' of return.

Edit: I'm looking for the action verb.

> He _____ her with affection.

or

> She ____ him with admiration.

Comment: Could you explain this statement a little more: [1] *if love is a stative verb, and all states are conditional, then 'unconditional love' does not accurately reflect agape.* To begin with, what do you mean by *all states are conditional?* (I might as well tell you where I'm going with this question: I'm suspecting that you are equivocating two different meanings of the word *conditional* in [1]. But I can't be sure one way or the other because I don't fully understand what [1] is saying.)

Comment: @linguisticturn there are two types of conditions, causal and existential.  Love doesn't appear out of nowhere, it's caused by something, and that something is conditional.  Existential conditions include everything going on now, and as it relates to 'states' or feelings, that includes not only what someone values, it also includes whatever triggers it existentially, and that whatever is conditional.  Does that help?

Comment: @linguisticturn I understand that Agape means to value something irregardless of the conditions, but that is not the same thing as 'feelings,' which my friends here have convinced me is what the word 'love' is...a stative verb.  When we feel love with no conditional triggers, it taps directly into the underlying value, and when we act based on that feeling/motivation, we are not loving unconditionally, we are loving based on the condition of consciously and intentionally focusing on the underlying value INSTEAD of any conditional triggers.  That is very intentional (action verb), not stative.

Comment: I'm still not following completely, but let me just address one thing. You seem to be reading some philosophical import to a verb being stative or dynamic. I am very skeptical about any claim that a grammatical property of a word can reveal any sort of deep philosophical meaning of the concept the word expresses. I bet e.g. that anything that can be said using active verbs can be said (perhaps awkwardly) using stative ones. Example: *I am now running,* which employs a dynamic verb *par excellence*, may be expressed as e.g. *I am now in a state of rapid locomotion,* which is definitely stative.

Comment: @linguisticturn lol, yes, that was awkward!  The way I understand things, we have meanings first and then find words to express them, unless we are learning from words, and then we have to synthesize the intended meaning into our understanding.  If I feel something, that is what I feel, and if I want to share what I feel, I can try to do it by what I do, or what I say; actions are vague, while words are/can be more descriptive.  We can make up whatever meaning we want to match what we feel, or use the generally accepted meaning, which we share on this site...and love is recognized as stative.

Comment: @linguisticturn  In other words, a word does not establish a philosophy, what you believe establishes that, but words express it, and the only way to do that effectively is with common meanings.  You and I can agree love means something specific, but when we use that word with others, we will fail to accurately convey what we mean, because they have a different meaning.  Agape has a specific meaning, but it is not widely used, unless we revive it's use or find the closest equivalent, and the stative verb love is not even close.  BTW, my field is neuropsychology and organizational development

Comment: So are you really looking for an English word that means *agape* (or, rather, the related verb *agapao*)? That famously doesn't exist, as generations of biblical scholars and interpreters can attest. As Acccumulation pointed out in their answer below, the word usually used is *charity*. It is all kinds of imperfect, but even C. S. Lewis [couldn't do better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Four_Loves#Agape_%E2%80%93_unconditional_%22God%22_love).

Comment: (I know you are not necessarily after the Christian concept of *agape*. But the point is, if there were a better English word—or managably short phrase—for what you *are* after, the Christian writers would have already found it and used it for their purposes.)

Comment: *"I learned from an earlier thread that the word, love, is not an action verb in English, it is a stative verb."* You may have misunderstood - stative verbs have an adjective (that defines the state) as a complement "*He is/becomes/feels **wise***", Dynamic/Action verbs take an adverb *He jumps/realizes/falls **wisely.*** -- "*Othello Act 5, scene 2, 340–346 Othello:... Then must you speak / Of **one that lov'd not wisely but too well;** -- love is a dynamic verb.

Answer (score 1):

The term "charity" largely means what you're looking for, but again it's a noun rather verb.

There's "no strings attached"

> Without conditions or restrictions, as in They give each of the children $10,000 a year with no strings attached. This expression dates from the mid-1900s, although string in the sense of “a limitation” has been used since the late 1800s.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/no-strings-attached

The phrase "left hand doesn't know what the right is doing" has come to be used to refer to dysfunction, but originally it's from Matthew 6:3

> But when thou doest alms, let not thy
> left hand know what thy right hand doeth:

This is talking about giving to charity without feeling that you're owed anything due to it.

Comment: Thanks @accumulation.  Charity meets a need...something they can't satisfy themself, and implies a superior position.  What I'm looking for is more benevolent, motivated by a wide range of emotions, from compassion to gratitude or pleasure...but most of all, I'm looking for the action verb.  "He _____ her with affection," or "She ____ him with admiration."

Comment: @Christopher "Charity" has acquired a negative connotation of condescension, but that's not its original meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I have no verbs to offer. However, you may consider the adjective ***selfless***:

> Having, exhibiting or motivated by no concern for oneself but for others ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/selfless.html#C0-1))

You could say:

> He *lavished* her with ***selfless*** affection. (you could also use *loved her*)

In your other sentence, I think the adjective ***sincere*** would imply "without any thought at the back of her mind":

> She *overwhelmed* him with ***sincere*** admiration.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I'm looking for the action verb.
>
> He **gave** her <s>with</s> affection **freely**.
>
> or
>
> She **gave** him <s>with</s> admiration **freely**.

To give. of itself, does not imply a motive.

**freely** = OED:

> **1.a.** Of one's own accord, spontaneously; without constraint or reluctance; **unreservedly, without stipulation**; readily, willingly.
>
> 1774   Story Aeneas & Dido Burlesqued 45   *I'd freely give a golden guinea If I could have a pickaninny.*
>
> 1862   J. Ruskin Unto this Last 82   *He may either give it us freely, or demand payment for it.*

Comment: Freedom is not the same thing as expecting nothing in return.  I can give freely but expect something in return--technically that is 'exchanging' or seducing, manipulating or encouraging, but most people don't recognize 'giving' is giving, not any of those things.  I deal with marriage counseling and other intimate relationships where exchanges are either implied or expected, so I'm looking for a way for people to distinguish between giving with, and without expectation of any kind.  When we marry for..."until death do us part," it's for life...not until someone doesn't give enough back....

Answer (score 0):

In amorous (or platonic) relationships, the verb that usually goes with *love* is **requite.**

> To respond to (another) or do something to or for (another) in return for that person's action or emotion:

*"If he love me to madness, I shall never requite him."*

(Shakespeare).

[AHD]

But i can see that *requite* doesn't meet your requirements.

I therefore suggest **shower**, which AHD defines as—

> To give or bestow something liberally or abundantly

> To give something in great abundance to: *showered their children with affection.*

This verb fits the bill quite nicely.

Comment: Showered was the word I thought of, but it doesn't include the element of being without expectation of receiving; it doesn't say anything about whether something is expected.

Comment: requite:- *He repaid her with affection* and *She repaid him with admiration* don't seem to fit with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Almost like altruism but I suppose that doesn't strictly concern love, nor is a verb:
'the principle or practice of unselfish concern for or devotion to the welfare of others'
Perhaps there isn't one verb but you could maybe use selflessly...

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).